# Concurrent execution in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to run multiple jobs concurrently with the below code, but it's running sequentially. Once the first job got completed then only its moving to next and so on.

May I know what am I doing wrong. Any helps/inputs appreciated.
Here is the code:

```
    def servers = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
    if ( servers != null )
    {
            for (i=0; i<servers.size(); i++)
             {
                 if (servers[i] != null)
                 {
                   def core = servers[i];
                   def stageName = "stage${core}"
                   stage(stageName){
                                stepsForMainJob[stageName] = { build job: 'mainJob', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'PARAM', value: core]]}
                           }
                     }
             }
    }
    parallel stepsForMainJob;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including the stage closure, so you can see all stages kick-off at once in Jenkins.

```
def servers = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
Map jobs = [:]
if ( servers != null ) {
    for (i=0; i<servers.size(); i++) {
        if (servers[i] != null) {
            def core = servers[i];
            def stageName = "stage${core}"

            jobs.put(stageName, { 
                stage(stageName) {
                    build job: 'mainJob', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'PARAM', value: core]]
                } 
            } )
        }
    }  
}
parallel(jobs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, It was scheduling all jobs at the same time, but the build still running sequentially.

Comment: From the logs you have posted, it appears to be executing in parallel.

If it was sequential, stagea would completely finish before stageb even gets scheduled/started.

Are your stages long enough to see them running at the same time?

By its nature, parallel will start from the start of the map, and kick-off all jobs one after another, but if jobs run > 5 seconds, you should see them all processing at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, It worked, I had not set Execute concurrent builds if necessary in my jobs after enabled it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks for the suggestion, It was scheduling all jobs at the same time, but the build still running sequentially.

Here is the o/p

[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] [stagea] { (Branch: stagea)
[Pipeline] [stageb] { (Branch: stageb)
[Pipeline] [stagec] { (Branch: stagec)
[Pipeline] [stagea] stage
[Pipeline] [stagea] { (stagea)
[Pipeline] [stageb] stage
[Pipeline] [stageb] { (stageb)
[Pipeline] [stagec] stage
[Pipeline] [stagec] { (stagec)
[Pipeline] [stagea] build (Building mainJob)
[stagea] Scheduling project: mainJob
[Pipeline] [stageb] build (Building mainJob)
[stageb] Scheduling project: mainJob
[Pipeline] [stagec] build (Building mainJob)
[stagec] Scheduling project: mainJob
[stagea] Starting building: mainJob #79
[Pipeline] [stagea] }
[Pipeline] [stagea] // stage
[Pipeline] [stagea] }
[stageb] Starting building: mainJob #80
[Pipeline] [stageb] }
[Pipeline] [stageb] // stage
[Pipeline] [stageb] }`enter code here`
[stagec] Starting building: mainJob #81
[Pipeline] [stagec] }
[Pipeline] [stagec] // stage
[Pipeline] [stagec] }
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```